# Match on two columns in two separate csv's then merge one column

Tags: powershell

I have 2 CSV's.

SOURCE CSV

```
"Employee ID","username","givenname","surname","emailaddress","title","Division","Location"
"204264","ABDUL.JALIL@domain.com","Abdul Jalil","Bin Hajar","Abdul.jalil@domain.com","Warehouse Associate I","Singapore","Singapore, "
"30053","ABEL.BARRAGAN@domain.com","Abel","Barragan","Abel.Barragan@domain.com","Manager, Customer Programs - CMS","Germany","Norderstedt, "
```

CHANGE CSV

```
givenname,surname,samaccountname,emailaddress,mail,country,city,state
Abigai,Teoyotl Rugerio,Abigai.Teoyotl,Abigai.TeoyotlRugerio@domain.com,Abigai.TeoyotlRugerio@domain.com,MX,,
Adekunle,Adesiyan,Adekunle.Adesiyan,Adekunle.Adesiyan@domain.com,Adekunle.Adesiyan@domain.com,US,VALENCIA,CALIFORNIA
```

I would like to match the surname and givenname from SOURCE to CHANGE, and if there is a match grab the "emailaddress" from the CHANGE CSV and place it into a new column in the SOURCE CSV.

So far I'm stuck on matching the first and last name columns.

```
$source = import-csv .\ur.csv
$change = import-csv .\all.csv

$Matchgivenname = Compare-Object $source.givenname $change.givenname -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru
$matchsurname = Compare-Object $source.surname $change.surname -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru
```

Comment: Your example doesn't makes any sense. No entry in your source.csv matches any in change.csv. Also source.csv already contains a emailaddress column.

Comment: So those are just the top few lines of each csv.  The source will contain some entries that are not in the change at all, and vice versa, however there will be some givennames and surnames that appear in both, and if they appear in both, i would like to grab the emailaddress from the change csv and add it to the source csv in a new column

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it with Compare-Object all at once, but you can loop over all the original employees and for each one, search for any changes. e.g.

```
$results = foreach ($employee in $source)
{
    $update = $change | Where-Object { $employee.surname -eq $_.surname -and $employee.givenname -eq $_.givenname } | Select -First 1

    if ($update)
    {
        $employee | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NewEmailAddress -Value $update.emailaddress
    }

    $employee
}
```

(untested)

Comment: I think this is putting me on the right track, it doesn't work per se but this gets me going.  What does the -first 1 do after the select?

Comment: It selects the first 1 thing from the pipeline, as a guard so that $update will never be an array of multiple matches, in case $change has the same person multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In case the `change` CSV is big and you only need the changed email address, build a hashtable with givenname+surname as a key and email as a value. Then use it while importing the source CSV.

Hashtable lookup is much faster than enumerating all rows of changed data, so overall number of iterations will be around `#changed + #source + log2(#changed)` where `#` stands for number of rows.

Also, since adding the new column via `Add-Member` is slower than direct assignment, add this new column just once using a custom header consisting of source fields extracted from the first row plus the changed email.

```
$changedEmail = @{}
Import-Csv .\all.csv |
    ForEach { $changedEmail[$_.givenname + '|' + $_.surname] = $_.emailaddress }

$newHeader = ((Import-Csv .\ur.csv | Select -first 1).PSObject.Properties |
    Select -expand name) + 'changedemailaddress'
$combined = Import-Csv .\ur.csv -Header $newHeader | Select -skip 1 |
    ForEach {
        $_.changedemailaddress = $changedEmail[$_.givenname + '|' + $_.surname]
        $_
    }
$combined
```